# Creating sub connections with azure-mobile-apps and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sqlite, express, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to create an API using nodeJS, express and azure-mobile-apps to do some data synchronisation between an Ionic3 mobile app (which use an SQLite local database) and a Microsoft SQL Database.

My API has to create a synchronisation connection for each mobile application. Each application will be linked to a distant database. For example, if user_01 wants to synchronise his data, he's going to be linked to his client_01 database. So each time it'll have to, the API will create a new process running on a different port.

here is an example : https://zupimages.net/up/19/36/szhu.png

The problem is that i'm not able to create more than one connection with azure-mobile-apps. The first one always works, but the second, third etc are still using the first connection that i have instantiated. I've looked into the app stack and everything seems fine.

Is that an issue with azure-mobile-app, or did I misunderstand something with express ?

Thanks for your responses !

```
var azureMobileApps = require('azure-mobile-apps');
var express = require('express');

module.exports = {
  async createConnection(client) {
    try {
      let app = express();      
      mobileApp = azureMobileApps({
        homePage: true,
        swagger: true,
        data: {
          server: '****',
          user: client.User,
          password: client.Password,
          port: '1443',
          database: client.Database,
          provider: 'mssql',
          dynamicSchema: false,
          options: {
            encrypt: false
          }
        }
      });
      await mobileApp.tables.import('./tables');
      await mobileApp.tables.initialize();
      app.listen(global.portCounter);    
      app.use(mobileApp);
      console.log(app._router.stack);
      console.log('Listening on port ',global.portCounter);
      global.portCounter++;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now. The thing is, it's impossible to do multiple connection with the azure-mobile-apps SDK for nodeJS.

I had to use worker-thread which seems to isolate the memory in a sub-proccess.

Hope it can help somebody one day